# Flutter wrap to end of next line

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget containing two (text) items, one of which has variable length. I want the second item to wrap to the end of the next line if space runs out.

[image: illustration of the desired behavior]

Flutter has a widget named `Wrap` which allows for wrapping content if space runs out, however I have not been able to get the desired result using all kinds of combinations of `Wrap`, `Expanded`, `Row` and `Spacer` widgets. The closest I got was the second element wrapping to the start of the second row, but I want it to go to the end of the second row.

I am fairly new to Flutter but have found ways to do it in CSS by placing the variable width element in a container and applying `flex: 1 0 auto` to the container and `flex-wrap: wrap` and `flex-justify: flex-end` to the flexbox containing both elements.

I tried putting the first element in an `Expanded`, but apparently putting an `Expanded` directly inside a `Wrap` is not allowed so that gave me errors and no results.

Comment: you want both element in same line and just to adjust their size

Answer (score 1):

Put the two sentences into a list like so:

```
List<TextSpan> reasonList = [TextSpan(text: 'sentence1'), TextSpan(text: 'sentence2') ];
```

Then:

```
              Container(
                    child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          children: reasonList,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
                    ),
                  );
```

This not only wraps but gives you more control over every sentence, like gesture detection and color changing.

Comment: So how would I use this to align element 2 to the right, and to have it wrap to the end of the next line if element 1 grows?